# seamless-immutable array property is not immutable

Tags: seamless-immutable

I wonder if there is a way to convert an object using seamless-immutable where the resultant immutable's array properties are also immutable, currently

```
a = {hey: [1,2,3], ho: {hi:'there'}}
ia = Immutable(a)
ia // immutable

ia.hey // not immutable
ia.ho //immutable
```

what I want is ia.hey, an array, being immutable as well, does anyone know how ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you can accomplish what you're asking about by using seamless-immutable in development mode. See here:

https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable#performance

> In the development build, objects are frozen. (Note that Safari is relatively slow to iterate over frozen objects.) The development build also overrides unsupported methods (methods that ordinarily mutate the underlying data structure) to throw helpful exceptions.

As it notes, this comes with a performance penalty (which is actually quite significant, but most likely not relevant in most scenarios).

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pvqzh9yj/

```
var array = Immutable(["totally", "immutable", {hammer: "Can’t Touch This"}]);

array[1] = "I'm going to mutate you!";

array[2].hammer = "hm, surely I can mutate this nested object...";

for (var index in array) {  console.log(array[index]); }
```

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks, I meant that an array property of an immutable object constructed by SI lacks the extra properties and methods normally seen in immutable objects, e.g, (asMutable(), setIn(), merge(), etc)

Comment: @NikSo - are you sure? I am not able to reproduce that. Is this what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/w2z05syb/ I am able to call asMutable on the inner array.